# Wordpress Grid Blog Posts, not responsive

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

Got a loop going in a grid formation. 3 posts per row, per category. Using bootstrap to create the layout. At full width it's working and how intended, however it's not responsive. Any ideas what I got wrong here?

Full Width
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x77wxxp5gmtdrs9/Screenshot%202017-06-20%2017.28.31.png?dl=0

Reduced Width (not responsive)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/01baalrm3u1fybe/Screenshot%202017-06-20%2017.32.42.png?dl=0

*Edited* Outputted html and css (written in sass originally).

```css
#blog-section {
  padding: 53px 0
}

#blog-section h1,
#blog-section h2,
#blog-section h3,
#blog-section h4,
#blog-section h5,
#blog-section h6,
#blog-section a {
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word
}

#blog-section h1 {
  color: #72b466;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd
}

#blog-section h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 12px
}

#blog-section h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 12px
}

#blog-section .blog-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto
}

#blog-section p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500px
}

#blog-section .blog-image {
  margin: 0 auto
}

#blog-section a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none !important
}

#blog-section .shortlink {
  color: crimson
}

#blog-section .custom-border {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

#blog-section .btn-home {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px
}

#blog-section .btn-list {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px
}

#blog-section .row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex
}

#blog-section .grid-loop {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, 0.15);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid gray
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="blog-section">
  <div class="container my-container">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="grid-loop">
          <div class="custom-border">
            <a class="perm_link" href="http://localhost/certified-compostable-products/">
              <h2>Certified Compostable Products</h2>
              <div class="blog-image image-responsive"><img width="251" height="250" src="http://img.dummy-image-generator.com/abstract/dummy-251x250-DesiccationCracks.jpg" class="attachment-img-251x250 wp-post-image" alt="image4" /></div>
            </a>
            <p>
              <p>&nbsp; PLEASE NOTE: We ALWAYS recommend that businesses replace disposable products with reusable ones. Waste reduction is the best way to handle your waste, followed by recycling and composting. Is there a way for you to stop using straws
                altogether, rather than looking for a compostable straw? Or coffee cup? Or plate? That’s the goal. [&hellip;]</p>
            </p>
            <span class="shortlink">
                            <button class="btn btn-success"><a rel="shortlink" href="http://localhost/?p=2382" title="Certified Compostable Products">Read More</a></button>
                        </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="grid-loop">
          <div class="custom-border">
            <a class="perm_link" href="http://localhost/importance-of-signage/">
              <h2>Importance of Signage</h2>
              <div class="blog-image image-responsive"><img width="251" height="250" src="http://img.dummy-image-generator.com/abstract/dummy-251x250-DesiccationCracks.jpg" class="attachment-img-251x250 wp-post-image" alt="image3" /></div>
            </a>
            <p>
              <p>You may have read the title of this post and thought: “Everyone knows how to recycle, do I really need to put up signs?” Yes you do! It’s very, very important, and it’s the law!. Most people know, or think they know, the basics of recycling,
                but when they are standing in front of three [&hellip;]</p>
            </p>
            <span class="shortlink">
                            <button class="btn btn-success"><a rel="shortlink" href="http://localhost/?p=2372" title="Importance of Signage">Read More</a></button>
                        </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="grid-loop">
          <div class="custom-border">
            <a class="perm_link" href="http://localhost/nycs-commercial-recycling-laws/">
              <h2>NYC&#8217;s Commercial Recycling Laws</h2>
              <div class="blog-image image-responsive"><img width="251" height="250" src="http://img.dummy-image-generator.com/abstract/dummy-251x250-DesiccationCracks.jpg" class="attachment-img-251x250 wp-post-image" alt="image1" /></div>
            </a>
            <p>
              <p>NYC’s commercial recycling laws are hard to keep up with and key information is often difficult to find. Don’t stress! We’ll help you stay up to date and in compliance. The most recent official notice regarding commercial recycling rules
                in NYC was released by the NYC Department of Sanitation on February 5, 2016. Link to [&hellip;]</p>
            </p>
            <span class="shortlink">
                            <button class="btn btn-success"><a rel="shortlink" href="http://localhost/?p=2356" title="NYC&#8217;s Commercial Recycling Laws">Read More</a></button>
                        </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.row-->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>


  </div>
  <!--/.container-->



</section>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you remove your php and share the html output please, in order to reproduce it in a fiddle.

Comment: OK, I edited that with html and css output.

Comment: And added bootstrap CDN

Answer (score 1):

Check your image container and your images, I think they're not responsive.
Your `.blog-image` class has a fixed width and the images within it should have `width` or `max-width` set to 100%.

EDIT

Also, if you are trying to use the Bootstrap class for image responsiveness, you should use the class `.img-responsive` in the `img` tag, not in its container. And the class name is `.img-responsive` and not `image-responsive`.

Comment: Thanks Yuri, I found the problem. It was the background, fixed border conflicting with responsiveness. I'm going to make a different view for smaller devices instead.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I editted my answer with new information, it might be useful for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added responsive meta tag in head section? If not, then add this tag:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` to head section of your html.

Comment: Did not for the example, but my local build has all the header, style, script, and meta tags needed. Added here, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was with the fixed height border.

```css
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
.grid-loop {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
```

Instead will make a media query that removes the border on smaller screen sizes.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .grid-loop {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
  }
}
```